# jQuery UI Datepicker won't close when double-clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/bC4PH/1/)

Reproduced in Chrome 18 on Ubuntu, Chrome Mac, and others.

Just double-click the link, then choose a date. The datepicker becomes unclosable. How do I fix this?

I wanted to check if the calendar was currently open before showing it again, but I [can't see a property for that](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

## HTML

```
<a href="#">double click me</a><input/>​
```

## JS

```
$('input').datepicker();
$('a').click(function() {
    $('input').datepicker('show');
});​
```

---

It seems to be a problem with the default fade animation. If you open it twice before the fade completes, the problem occurs. Setting `duration` to `0` fixes the problem, but I kind of like the fade animation.

---

I submitted a [bug report](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8311). Which is actually [a dupe](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8174).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, except the fact that you **DON'T** double click it, you just click it once, then click elsewhere to close it, if you want it for double clicking then use `.dblclick()`

Comment: @ChristopherKenney You cannot enforce such conditions on end users who may double/triple click and say it broke because he double clicked.

Comment: @ChristopherKenney: Yes, I know, but my users aren't that smart. They like to double-click things. This can't just stop working because someone accidentally double-clicks something, that's ridiculous.

Comment: @Mark Where did you get this `$('input').datepicker('show');` - Couldn't find it in docs

Comment: @Vega - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-show

Comment: "the input must be visible for the datepicker to be shown" -- the documentation is actually misleading. I'm using a hidden input in my real application, and it works fine, but that's besides the point here  :-)

Comment: Seems like this could be considered a datepicker() bug.

Comment: @j08691: It certainly does. I'm going to leave this question open a bit longer... if no one says otherwise, I'll report it....if they have a bug-tracker somewhere.

Comment: Seems like the same happens when you focus and blur on the textbox quickly. I tried a solution with focus() but it failed because it is just not double click, it is something to do with the fade animation flipping status quickly leaving the status as closed event though the second click opened it.

Comment: @j08691: Thanks. Submitted. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8311

Comment: This was fixed in a fairly recent release of jQuery UI: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed via [Ticket #8174](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8174). If you are having this problem, try upgrading to a newer version of jQuery UI.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input').datepicker();
$status = true;
$('a').click(function() {
    if ($status){
        $('input').datepicker('show');
            $status = false;
    }
    else{
    $('input').datepicker('hide');
        $status = true;
    }    
});
```

this might work as you want it

Comment: Appears to work. I'd have to make sure that variable stays in sync with the actual status of the datepicker though.

Comment: Thanks mattematico. I've got 20K rep; I think I've figured out how SO works. I'm not accepting this because it's not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
$('a').dblclick(function() {
    if ($('input').datepicker('widget').is(':visible')) {
        $('input').datepicker('hide');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Did you try it? Doesn't work for me. Also, the problem occurs when you click twice before the animation completes, it's not actually specific to double-clicks (AFAICT), thus even if this hack did work, it wouldn't work for longer durations if the user timed it perfectly.